# React Native iOS Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'allRowIDs.length')

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have been trying React Native and Firebase with the iOS steps mentioned in this link https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/the-beginners-guide-to-react-native-and_84.html

I want to first follow ***Static Mockup*** steps mentioned in this link. I have followed the steps and provided the code as it is, but when I run the app in Xcode.

```
2017-10-17 01:25:19.743 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'allRowIDs.length')

This error is located at:
        in ListView (at index.js:64)
        in RCTView (at View.js:113)
        in View (at index.js:60)
        in ReactFirebaseSample (at renderApplication.js:35)
        in RCTView (at View.js:113)
        in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
        in RCTView (at View.js:113)
        in View (at AppContainer.js:126)
        in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
```

Please advise, how to fix this error?

Here is the index.JS code:

```
'use strict';

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactNative from 'react-native';
const firebase = require('firebase');
const StatusBar = require('./components/StatusBar');
const ActionButton = require('./components/ActionButton');
const ListItem = require('./components/ListItem');
const styles = require('./styles.js')

const {
  AppRegistry,
  ListView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  AlertIOS,
} = ReactNative;


// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "AIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
authDomain: "fir-realtime-dc900.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://fir-realtime-dc900.firebaseio.com",
storageBucket: "fir-realtime-dc900.appspot.com",
};
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactFirebaseSample', () => ReactFirebaseSample);

class ReactFirebaseSample extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      })
    };
  }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
                      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows([{ title: 'Pizza' }])
                      })
    }

    _renderItem(item) {
      return (

        <ListItem item={item} onpress={() => {}}/>
      );
    }


    render() {
        return (
          <View style="{styles.container}">

            <StatusBar title="Grocery List"/>

            <ListView datasource="{this.state.dataSource}" renderrow="{this._renderItem.bind(this)}" style="{styles.listview}/"/>


            <ActionButton title="Add" onpress={() => {}} />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: When providing some type of parameter other than string you don't use `"`. `datasource="{this.state.dataSource}"` should be `datasource={this.state.dataSource}`. Change other props accordingly.

Comment: Correct. it worked now

Comment: Such a crappy, useless error message, React Native is a pig to debug.